# How to right align fixed position div inside a div

Tags: html, css

My code is like this.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    max-width:1024px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.inner {
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    position:fixed;
}
```

The inner `div`, which is positioned `left` by default, needs to be positioned against the `right` w.r.t. the outer `div` and not to the page itself.

If I style it to be `right:0px;`, then it aligns `0px` from the browser's right, not the outer `div`'s right.

NOTE : My outer `div` is not fixed width; it adjust as per screen resolution. It's a responsive website design.

Comment: Thanks, I has to add max-width along with the % width, but it makes the perfect solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a container div:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="floatcontainer">
        <div class="inner">some text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use that to handle the `float`, and make its child `position: fixed`

```
.outer {
    width:50%;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.floatcontainer {
    float: right;
}
.inner {
    border:1px solid white;
    position:fixed;
}
.floatcontainer, .inner{
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you use `position:absolute`

`position:fixed` always relative to the browser

```
.outer {
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative
}
.inner {
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    position:absolute; right:0
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLbqn/)

---

If it is compulsory to use `position:fixed` then you can assign the `margin-left` value, since you are using fixed with for both the divs.

```
.inner {
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    position:fixed; margin-left:150px
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLbqn/2/)**

Comment: your second solution seems to be working but the problem with that my outer div is not fixed width. It adjust itself according to the screen width. So i can't declare width's inside that. I have updated the same in my query

Comment: @RavishKumar what is the problem using position:absolute

Comment: what i want is that it should be 20% from top and inside main body div fixed.

Comment: As I explained in the first attempt, position:fixed is always relative to the browser

Answer (score 6):

Two options. Simply float the inner div right or else use absolute positioning to achieve it.

For floating simply set float:right on the inner DIV and overflow:hidden on the outer DIV.

For absolute positioning simply set position:relative on the outer DIV and set position: absolute and right:0 top:0 on the inner DIV.

Comment: neither of these work with `position: fixed`, and I'm not sure how `overflow: hidden` would help.

Comment: it's making it aligned to the page not the outer div

Comment: @Twon-ha - Adding overflow:hidden to a parent container that contains floating child elements allows the parent container to grow in height to contain the floating children.

Comment: @RavishKumar - I can only assume you didn't implement my solution(s) exactly as I outlined them.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">some text here
    </div>
</div>


.outer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 860px;
    direction: rtl;
    background-color: black;
    height: 1200px;
}

.inner {
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If in case, you want to make the `.inner` element as a fixed positioned element and leave the other things inside `.outer` to be *"scrollable"*, I suggest you to set the `.inner` position as an absolute positioned element. Then, create a new wrapper after it with `overflow:auto`:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Some text here...</div>
  <div class="flow">content</div> <!-- extra markup -->
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/ZLbqn/3/

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="overlay">
        overlay content
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but it works

```
.outer {
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    direction: rtl; 
}
.inner {
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    direction: ltr;
}
```