# How to Move DIV with Header and Unordered List to the Right and Up on Webpage

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to move a block of text "Previous Guesses" over to the right side of the web page and up a little bit.

I have tried a bunch of CSS manipulations but I can't seem to get the box with text inside to budge (it's always centered).

HTML:

```
<div id="game-box" class="center">
      <h2>Previous Guesses</h2>

      <ul id="guess-list">
        <li class="guess">Guess #1   |  ?  |</li>
        <li class="guess">Guess #2   |  ?  |</li>
        <li class="guess">Guess #3  |  ?  |</li>
        <li class="guess">Guess #4  |  ?  |</li>
        <li class="guess">Guess #5  |  ?  |</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#game-box {
    align-content: right;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 10%;
}


.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 100px;
}


div {
    align: right;
}

li {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}


h2 {
    color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Here's what my webpage looks like now:

[image]

I want that entire white box including the words "Previous Guesses" and "Guess #1 etc" to move to the right and up on the webpage.

Comment: What is the style for the parent container of the #game-box? This might help in positioning a div within a div: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154790/how-to-right-align-fixed-position-div-inside-a-div

Comment: there is no style from what i can see

Comment: what is the rest of the html structure and what is the css layout ?  what have you tried ? did you consider the grid box model which allows you to tzll where element should be ? ... clarify your question, else the answer might be psoition:absolute, right:0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you would go about this depends on what you mean by "over the the right side of the webpage and up a little bit", and on what the context of the game-box element is.

If you game-box to be be positioned in the top-right corner of its parent element, for example, give game-box the following style:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

If you want game-box to be moved up 200 pixels and right 200 pixels relative to its default position in the document, for example, give it the following style:

```
position: relative;
left: 200px;
top: -200px;
```

If you'd like to give game-box a fixed position on the page, you could remove it from its current parent, add it as a child of `body`, and position it absolutely within that context. Or, within its current context, assign it a `fixed` position, then the positioning values will be within the context of the viewport.